# Permission denied when I try to restore postgres backup

Tags: postgresql, debian

Recently I used this command to make a backup of my postgres databases

```
pg_dumpall > BkpOldPG.sql
```

After removing the old version of postgres I downloaded the last version **9.4** and I have tried to restore my old data using :

```
mody@debian:~$ su postgres
Password: 
postgres@debian:/home/mody$
postgres@debian:/home/mody$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/psql -d postgres -f Documents/Bkp01dPg.sql 
Documents/Bkp01dPg.sql: Permission denied
```

As you can see I get **Permission denied** so I tried using **sudo** but it doesn't work :

```
postgres@debian:/home/mody$ sudo /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/psql -d postgres -f Documents/Bkp01dPg.sql 
[sudo] password for postgres: 
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

any help with that please ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your backup file, or the `Documents` folder it is within, have permissions that do not permit access by the `postgres` user.

You can give the `postgres` user (and all other users on your system) the right to read them with:

```
chmod a+x Documents
chmod a+r Documents/Bkp01dPg.sql
```

Alternately, you could copy `Bkp01dPg.sql` into a location that the `postgres` user already has access to, then give the `postgres` user ownership of it, e.g.

```
sudo cp Documents/Bkp01dPg.sql ~postgres/
sudo chown postgres ~postgres/Bkp01dPg.sql
```

Or you could run the restore under your normal user account, connecting to PostgreSQL as a superuser:

```
psql -U postgres -f Documents/Bkp01dPg.sql
```

... though you might need to modify `pg_hba.conf` or `pg_ident.conf` to allow your user to connect as `postgres` if you do it this way. (Or you could temporary `ALTER USER` to give your normal user superuser rights).

By the way, you don't need to `su` to `postgres`. Get in the habit of using `sudo -u postgres` to run commands, and `sudo -u postgres -i` if you want an interactive command line.

Comment: Yes you're right. I already solved it, I've run the command as debian user (normal user) and it worked perfectly. But your explanation is much clear and gives me a better idea about my error! and it's the right way to do with. thanks!

Comment: can you tell me which is the best place to start learning about postgres. I use it in my apps but I feel that I know nothing about it !

Comment: @medBo I started by reading the manual cover-to-cover. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/ . You'll probably also find the Ubuntu Community Wiki pages on PostgreSQL informative if you use Debian or Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL . There's a bit of a gap in the docs for things like this issue, though, where it's really a UNIX issue not a PostgreSQL issue, but it's something PostgreSQL users will run into easily.

Comment: thank you for the resources I will check them and may be do like you cover-to-cover :D

Answer (score 1):

I tried many different solutions for restoring my postgres backup. I ran into permission denied problems on MacOS, no solutions seemed to work.

Here's how I got it to work:

Postgres comes with Pgadmin4. If you use macOS you can press `CMD`+`SPACE` and type `pgadmin4` to run it. This will open up a browser tab in chrome.

> If you run into errors getting pgadmin4 to work, try `killall pgAdmin4` in your terminal, then try again.

---

## Steps to getting pgadmin4 + backup/restore

### 1. Create the backup

Do this by rightclicking the database -> "backup"

[image]

### 2. Give the file a name.

Like `test12345`. Click backup. This creates a binary file dump, it's not in a `.sql` format

[image]

### 3. See where it downloaded

There should be a popup at the bottomright of your screen. Click the "more details" page to see where your backup downloaded to

[image]

### 4. Find the location of downloaded file

In this case, it's `/users/vincenttang`

[image]

### 5. Restore the backup from pgadmin

Assuming you did steps 1 to 4 correctly, you'll have a restore binary file. There might come a time your coworker wants to use your restore file on their local machine. Have said person go to pgadmin and restore

Do this by rightclicking the database -> "restore"

[image]

### 6. Select file finder

Make sure to select the file location manually, DO NOT drag and drop a file onto the uploader fields in pgadmin. Because you will run into error permissions. Instead, find the file you just created:

[image]

### 7. Find said file

You might have to change the filter at bottomright to "All files". Find the file thereafter, from step 4. Now hit the bottomright "Select" button to confirm

[image]

### 8. Restore said file

You'll see this page again, with the location of the file selected. Go ahead and restore it

[image]

### 9. Success

If all is good, the bottom right should popup an indicator showing a successful restore. You can navigate over to your tables to see if the data has been restored propery on each table.

### 10. If it wasn't successful:

Should step 9 fail, try deleting your old public schema on your database. Go to "Query Tool"

[image]

Execute this code block:

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

[image]

Now try steps 5 to 9 again, it should work out

## Summary

This is how I had to backup/restore my backup on Postgres, when I had error permission issues and could not log in as a superuser. Or set credentials for read/write using `chmod` for folders.